# How do I view values in R so I can start manipulating and visualizing them?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm working with the 'uspop' dataset in Tidyverse. It has 19 values I want to view but don't know how to view them all to make vizulizations and manipulations.

I can't get beyond here

```
library(tidyverse)

data()
uspop
```

Is there a function I need to call to view all 19 variables?

Comment: You might want to check `?uspop` for a basic visualization example and an actual description (it's just a time series of 19 values).

Comment: Try `print(uspop)`.

Comment: `View(uspop)` will open your data in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple two lines of code solution to be able to view all 19 values in the data:

```
uspop_tib <- tibble(uspop) # convert data into a tibble


print(uspop_tib) # print tibble to console



        <dbl>
     1   3.93
     2   5.31
     3   7.24
     4   9.64
     5  12.9 
     6  17.1 
     7  23.2 
     8  31.4 
     9  39.8 
    10  50.2 
    11  62.9 
    12  76   
    13  92   
    14 106.  
    15 123.  
    16 132.  
    17 151.  
    18 179.  
    19 203.
```

I hope it helps!